# .pop() removes elements from original list

Tags: python, list, methods

While creating a quiz game I came across this weird discovery, when using .pop() method on a list that is a copy of another list, the original list's items are removed.
I wrote this simple code to let you better understand what I mean:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myListDup = myList
print("{}\n{}".format(myListDup, myList))

for i in range(len(myList)):
    myListDup.pop()

print("{}\n{}".format(myListDup, myList))
```

As this shows, after using .pop() to remove all the elements from myListDup, myList is empty aswell (I know there are other ways to remove elements, but I need to use .pop() in my original program)
Are there ways to avoid this?

Comment: Use `myListDup = myList.copy()` or `myListDup = myList[:]`, direct assignment does not copy a Python object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing `myListDup = myList` this is just creating another reference `myListDup` to the original list `myList`.

Try this:

```
myListDup = list(myList)
```

or

```
myListDup = myList[:]
```

This will create a new copy of the list and then assign it to `myListDup`

Answer (score 0):

Use `copy()`,

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myListDup = myList.copy()
print("{}\n{}".format(myListDup, myList))

for i in range(len(myList)):
    myListDup.pop()

print("{}\n{}".format(myListDup, myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list `copy` method for copying the list

Like,

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
copy_list = my_list.copy()
my_list.pop()
print(my_list)
print(copy_list)
```

Output

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```